# Javascript function as parameter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I want on a form submit to check geolocation. If it's the good one the form will submit, if not, it won't
For now I just want to get coordinationates, so I have:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var isGoodLocation = false;
$(function() {
    $('.submit').on('submit', function(event) {
        getLocation();
        if (!isGoodLocation) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            alert("Form Submission prevented / stoped.");
        }

    });
});

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude
            + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    isGoodLocation = false;
}
```

If I set getLocation() on a simple button it works, but if it's set on my class="submit" form it is not entering in showPosition function,
Does anyone know why?

Later edit:
Answer in commentaries, by  @dandavis, thank you

Comment: it's a matter of timing. the submit event finished before the gps info returns.

Comment: is there a way to make it wait the gps info?

Comment: yeah, return false in the human-clicked submit, and then call form.submit() in the gps calback

Comment: it worked, thank you so much!